# mean reversion model estimation - what method?

Tags: models, estimation, mean-reversion, mean

how can I estimate this model for mean reversion?
[image]

Comment: Assuming you are interested in continuous time please google calibration of Ornstein Uhlenback process. For discrete you can use the usual econometric AR1.

Comment: please replace your scans by a manually edited question. This is a little effort that will help contributors: to find your question when searching on quant.stackexchange, and it will clarify your question.